# Aligning thumbnails along columns using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been playing with twitter-bootstrap to create my photography page. I am using the default thumbnail class within li tags to create the border and align them. I have a whole bunch of thumbnails with images which are both horizontal and vertical.

The default settings really does not create a pretty layout of the thumbnails. By adding fixed height in the thumbnail's CSS, at least a neat grid gets formed now. However, within the thumbnail block, the images always align to the top. This leads to odd shaped grids when there is a vertical image in the stack.

I tried adding "vertical-align: middle;" within the thumbnail class, but does not seem to be working. I am pretty new to CSS, so kindly pardon me if I am missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Bootstrap thumbnails don't really normalize for a fixed height. If you want to make sure you have a clean grid, you need to crop your images to the same size. You could, alternately, use some CSS of your own to set the height of the `li` manually and set the `img` max-height to 100%, then use `display: table-cell` on the `li` so your `vertical-align: middle` will actually be effective at vertically centering the `img`.